# Firebase FCM tokens becoming invalid

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I run an Android app that has users that wish to stay registered for push notifications indefinitely, and many use the app for years. I switched over my push notifications to Firebase last spring, and I'm now getting a significant number of users complaining who, after receiving notifications for months without issue, no longer receive notifications (when I try to send to the tokens I have in my database for them, I get either a `InvalidRegistration` or `NotRegistered`, not sure which tbh).

Is anyone else having this issue, and is it an issue with Firebase FCM itself? Perhaps `onTokenRefresh` isn't being called when it should be at times or something? (I'm certain that my code to give a refreshed token to the server is solid - I had no problems for years with the old GCM, although I had to have a bunch of hacks to re-register periodically in addition to when the user updated the app or the OS)

I see that `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken()` can throw an `IOException`, perhaps that is killing my `onTokenRefresh` method before it can start sending the token to the server? Do robust apps take this possibility into account and have a mechanism to retry on failure?

Basically, just looking into any insight into why this is happening, if others are having the same issue, and any workarounds people have found. At the end of my rope over here:/

Comment: If you could determine a minimum amount of time that a token remains valid you could use an approach of settings a job scheduler to try to run a service every X days and  validate / renew it. Although I remember google says there are slight changes to token life, I'd love to see the official docs with such details. Do you have any trends in android 7 users having more problems?

Comment: Yeah I've thought of that, though it seems the only way to renew it is to invalidate the old one, which could lead to a bit of downtime in the app's availability to receive notifications, and might be unnecessary in the future if this is a bug on Google's end. onTokenRefresh should be called whether or not I manually refresh the token though if Google renews it themselves...

Comment: Oh and no, I've noticed users on Android 6 reporting the same issue